# NTP - Clock is not syncing to low stratum server

Tags: linux, open-source, timing, ntp

## Issue Summary

Open NTP - Version `4.2.6p3` - Clock is not syncing to low stratum server.

## Issue Description

1. I am running a NTP Unicast Client in my Ubuntu system.
2. I have 3 servers, `Server1-Stratum=13, Server2-Stratum=5, Server3-Stratum=4`.
3. Clock is not syncing to Server3 rather it is syncing to Server1.

## Queries

1. Whether this is a expected behavior ? Because as per my understanding NTP Client should sync to Low stratum server.
2. How NTP Daemon will decide server for sync, by configuration order or by stratum ?

## Outputs of `ntpq -np`

### Client

```
root@hmllab:~# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
x172.31.112.136  LOCAL(0)        13 u   14   16  377    0.255  -27.571   0.340
x172.31.112.139  LOCAL(0)         5 u    5   16  377    0.211  -126229   3.221
x172.31.112.142  LOCAL(0)         4 u    5   16  377    0.160  -946075   1.078
root@hmllab:~#
root@hmllab:~#
root@hmllab:~# date
Wed Jan  1 01:46:06 UTC 2020
root@hmllab:~#
```

### Server 1

```
root@hmlpc136 ~ $
root@hmlpc136 ~ $ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          12 l   47   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.001
root@hmlpc136 ~ $
root@hmlpc136 ~ $
root@hmlpc136 ~ $date
Wed Jan  1 01:46:13 UTC 2020
root@hmlpc136 ~ $
```

### Server 2

```
[root@hmlpc139 ~]#
[root@hmlpc139 ~]# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*127.127.1.0     .LOCL.           4 l   13   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.000
[root@hmlpc139 ~]#
[root@hmlpc139 ~]# date
Fri Jan  1 01:53:44 UTC 2016
[root@hmlpc139 ~]#
[root@hmlpc139 ~]#
```

### Server 3

```
root@hmllab-OptiPlex-3020:~#
root@hmllab-OptiPlex-3020:~# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*127.127.1.0     .LOCL.           3 l   12   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.000
root@hmllab-OptiPlex-3020:~#
root@hmllab-OptiPlex-3020:~#
root@hmllab-OptiPlex-3020:~# date
Sun Jan  1 01:53:35 UTC 2017
root@hmllab-OptiPlex-3020:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ntpq -np` is showing with the `x` at the start of the line
that all three of your servers are *falsetickers*.  Basically, none of
your servers agree with each other, so none are chosen. See the discussion
at [ntp.org](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/SelectingOffsiteNTPServers#Section_5.3.3.). You would be better off with one server!

Perhaps after a few hours your stratum 4 server will be chosen.  Of course, the
date may still not change as the time difference is too great. It depends
on your config.

Comment: Hi meuh thanks for the details, can you please clarify the following points,

Comment: 1. When the servers will agree with each other ? **I tried with 1 minute difference between servers** `(Server-1-Clock=9:10:00, Server-2-Clock=9:11:00 and Server-3-Clock=9:12:00)` at that time also it shows all are false tickers.

Comment: 2. _Perhaps after a few hours your stratum 4 server will be chosen_ 
When it will happen ? I waited for 4 hours...

Comment: You really need the 3 servers to sync between themselves, instead of being standalone, then they will all merge into a time standard that any client will be happy to sync to. Sorry, I'm not an ntp expert, but using a local clock that is just the cpu of a pc is not a good clock.

Comment: Hi meuh, thanks for your support, clock selection mechanism may be changed please verify http://bugs.ntp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2093

Comment: HI meuh, it seems **jitter** playing the major role in selecting the time source - http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo-real.htm#AEN2484

Comment: Interesting article. Did you know some linux distributions, like Fedora, are now moving over 
to [chronyd](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) instead of `ntpd` to sync between machines? 
It uses the same protocol but claims to be "better" for machines which are not often connected 
to the internet.